# how to bring to front task the already started this activity on the back stack

Tags: android, android-activity, task

How to bring to front the task that already started  activity (this activity can be on the stack back) if anther task wants to start this activity.
I tried to do this with intent and flags but it isn't helping. the new task starts root activity and not brings  to front the task that already started this  activity.
 tasks created not from the same application

on netbeans I have 2 application the one that  start app B
and the second app  b that user can start it directly from device.

hope you can help.If can give some code

Comment: can u give an example, It is not that understandable, May be my fault!!

Comment: use launch mood of your `Activity` as `singleInstance`

Comment: my Activities aren't singleInstance exapt the splash activity,

Comment: my Activities aren't singleInstance exapt the splash activity, edit singleInstance to splash activity but when test it still the same result the secont task always get root activity and not bring the first task to the front

Comment: If your splash is `singleInstance` then this is likely the root of your problem. You don't need a `singleInstance` activity. This is for HOME-screen replacements only. Please post your manifest (at least show all acitvities, filters and launchModes) and show us how you tried to bring the task to the front.

Comment: [See this post, maybe it will help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21215613/1876355

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand the question correctly, but if do then maybe you could somehow use `startActivityForResult()`? In such situation root activity (started for a result) might get a message that in this very situation it should start (or bring to front) yet another activity.

Taking care of the device BACK key (so it does not come back to the root activity) could be accomplished with i.e. flags.